# How do I get how long the file was created in seconds in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script that deletes a file that was created 1 day ago, and I need to calculate how long was the file created in seconds, but I don't know how, can anyone help?

Comment: How long was the file created? You mean how long your script was executing?

Comment: no, how long was the file created in seconds

Comment: Ah, you mean how long ago was the file created? You need to check whether a day has passed based on file creation date?

Comment: get the time now, get the time of creation, use https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php to get the interval between them. The interval can tell you how long in various time measurements the difference is. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, that's it

Comment: @ADyson, thank you, I'll see if it works

Comment: I'm pretty sure the internet will already have precise examples of how to get the time difference between two dates using PHP, if you search around.

Comment: @ADyson Since everything is in seconds and they want seconds just `-`

Comment: @AbraCadaver even better then. I wasn't sure, off the top of my head, what format the time would come back in when the creation time was read from the filesystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php

You can use the `filectime` function to get the creation date of your file. The function returns a unix timestamp. You could then subtract that time from the current time to get the amount of seconds ago the file was made.

```php
<?php

# Get the creation date of the file in unix timestamp
$creationDate = filectime("myfile.txt");

# Subtract the creation date from the current time, to get the time difference in seconds
$secondsAgo = time() - $creationDate;

?>
```

Please note that on most unix systems it will return the last modified date instead of the creation date. This is because on most unix systems the creation date does not exist like on windows.

Comment: Then subtract that from current `time` to get seconds ago.

Answer (score 0):

The following script displays files that are changed in +1 day, on the folder /path:

```
<?php
$path_to_dir ='/path/';
$timenow = time();
if ($handle = opendir($path_to_dir)) {

            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

                            if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !is_dir("$path_to_dir$entry")) {
                                    $modified_date = filemtime("$path_to_dir$entry");
                                    if (($timenow - $modified_date)> 86400){
                                            echo "$path_to_dir$entry\n";
                                    }
                                                        }
                                }

                closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: So the short answer is `filemtime("$path_to_dir$entry")`, or did you just copy the code from elsewhere?

Answer (score -1):

Use `filectime`. For Windows it will return the creation time, and for Unix the change time which is the best you can get because on Unix there is no creation time
good luck :)